# How to pass data from controller to view via json on CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass data from controller to view via json, after event in my main login page. Login page js looks like:

```
$('#submit_loginform').live('click',function(){

    $("#error_message").fadeIn(500).html("<img src='images/loaders/loader2.gif' alt='loading' />"); // debug message area

    //var login_name  = $("#login").val();
    //var pass        = $("#pass").val();

    var data        = {
        name        : $("#login").val(),
        password    : $("#password").val(),
        ajax        : 1
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "home/login_validation", // my home controller function "login_validation:
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {

            if(data.message){
              alert(data.message);
            } 
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });

 });
```

And my controller looks like:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){

       $data = array(
            "text" => "Welcome",
            "time" => date("Y/m/d")
       );

       $this->load->view('home_view.php', $data);
    }

    public function login_validation(){

        $array = array(
            "message" => "all things are beutiful"
        );

        $data['json'] = json_encode($array);
        $this->load->view('login_view.php', $data);        
    }

}
```

and after all, when I'm trying to submit data, I should receive an alert with text "all things are beutiful", but the alert is not "poping up".

Btw i checked it with firebug for response, and the response is the same HTML code from my home_view file.

What is wrong? What I should do to receive normall response from controller?

Comment: what is in `login_view.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your ajax function is expecting json as a response.

You could accomplish this by echoing json string directly, or having your view render one.

```
public function login_validation(){

    $array = array(
        "message" => "all things are beutiful"
    );

    $data['json'] = $array;
    echo json_encode($data);          
}
```

---

```
// js
alert(response.json.message);
```

Comment: you right, now I'm receiving alert with text "{"json":"{\"message\":\"all things are beutiful\"}"}" in my data.json response. How should I convert it to array, that I can type only data.message and get "all things are beutiful" ?

Comment: one more thing, how should I receive input value? I tried "message" => $this->input->post('login') but it's not working for me.. input name is login // edit -> oops, i'm dealed with that too

Comment: @user2304363 it doesn't look like you are posting a `login` param
`$this->input->post('name')`